# Make shortcode work in post tile when it's 'entry-title'

Tags: php, wordpress, title, shortcode

I've been trying to get a shortcode to work in my post titles on wordpress however the usual method isn't working.

The theme is using 'entry-title' but i can't find the correct tag to use.

So far i've gone with:

```
 function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

and i've also used...

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Neither them are working and when i change 'the title' to 'entry-title', still no success

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will work

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

You are calling do_shortcode need to be a call back and not a shortcode
So make a call back function instead and in the call back function do

```
echo do_shortcoe
```

that will work